# Inserting a character into a char array

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, arduino, char

I have a char array containing a number.

```
char number[] = "12000000"
```

I need to have a function to **insert** a divider in every 3 digits. Like:

```
char result[] = "12,000,000"
```

My function accepts the number  as a `char pointer` and it needs to return result as a `char pointer` too.

```
  char* insert_divider(char* number) {

    some magic;
    return result;
  }
```

I have no idea of working with pointers. Thanks.

Comment: How is the string terminated? Is the array big enough to hold the new string?

Comment: I tried a lot of methods and it seems that it terminates with \0 . This array of numbers is 14 digits at most.

Comment: You generally do not insert into a C-style array. You can only reuse array elements which are already there. You cannot add to the number of elements. You can only hope that there are a few unused ones at the end and then shift the alreaedy used ones around to have unused ones between them. Is that what you are asking about? Or do you hope to  do the adding elements thing?

Comment: (1) Use `strlen` to calculate the input length, and multiply by 2. (2) Use `char *result = malloc(size)` to allocate enough memory (3) Write a `for` loop to copy characters to `result` Make sure `result` is null terminated. See some [example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_malloc.htm) to get started.

Comment: Thanks for wonderful explaination. I don't need to preserve or edit first array. I just have to come up with an array with new format.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Thanks for helping me. My main problem is how to extract some chars from the first array. any hint on that?

Comment: Try this `int len = strlen(input); for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) printf("%c", input[i]);`. Then insert characters in to `result[i]`. Note `result` can't be an "array" because the array is destroyed when the function returns. It has to be a pointer, and it's memory is allocated with `malloc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have a function that adds char `c` every `num` characters starting from the end. You need to make sure that the string buffer is long enough to accommodate the amended string.

```
char *addEvery(char *str, char c, unsigned num)
{
    char *end = str;

    if(str && *str && num)
    {
        size_t count = 1;
        while(*(end)) end++;
        while(end != str)
        {
            end--;
            count++;
            if(!(count % (num + 1)) && str != end)
            {
                memmove(end + 1, end, count);
                *end = c;
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return str;
}

int main(void)
{
    char str[100] = "120000000000";
    printf("%s", addEvery(str,',',3));
}
```

Comment: `addEvery()` should absolutely take the buffer length as an argument and refuse to write past the buffer's end. Otherwise there's a disaster just waiting to happen...

Comment: Something has to be left for OP

Comment: You haven't left much.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this piece of code:

```
  char *result;
  result = (char*) malloc(15);
  int len= strlen(input);
  uint8_t cursor= 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if ((len- i) > 0 && (len- i) % 3 == 0) {
      result[i + cursor] = ',';
      cursor++;
    }
    result[i + cursor] = input[i];
  }
  result[len+ cursor] = '\0';
```

Thanks everyone for help and advice.

Comment: For `112000000` you get an extra `,` at index zero. Try changing to `if (i &&  (len - i) % 3 == 0)`. Also, I recommend changing to `result = malloc(len * 2);`, then it can handle any number. Don't forget to call `free(result)` when no longer need it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to do it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* insert_divider(char* number, size_t length) {
    int j = length + length/3; // every 3 digits a ',' will be inserted
    char *out = (char*)malloc(j + 1);

    out[j--] = '\0';

    for (int i = length - 1, k = 1; i >= 0; i--, k++) {
        out[j--] = number[i];
        if ((k%3) == 0) {
            out[j--] = ',';
        }
    }

    return out;
}

int main(){
    char number[] = "12000000";
    char *outNumber = insert_divider(number, strlen(number));
    printf("%s", outNumber);
    free(outNumber);
    return 0;
}
```